# Minecraft forge 1.7.4 can't install

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have several versions of minecraft installed (1.5.2, ..., 1.7.2, 1.7.4). When i use forge installer, it installs forge for minecraft 1.7.2 instead of 1.7.4. I tried to remove 1.7.2 and then got following error while installing forge: You need to run the version 1.7.2 manually at least once. What to do?

I read that there are some differences between 1.7.2 and 1.7.4 and because of them, forge can't be installed. If it is so, where can I get forge for 1.7.4?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support for modded minecraft is off-topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 1):

Forge for 1.7.4 isn't released yet.  Forge 1.7.2 was just released this week

Answer (score 1):

There is not yet forge 1.7.4
You could see the updates from this: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Forge is not available for 1.7.4 [image]. If you want forge for 1.7.4, it is a long process of decompiling, editing code and recompiling. Anyway, there are no mods for 1.7.4. All those that you see are either fake or they require you to edit the 1.7.4.jar file. To install forge, I assume you use the new launcher(you should!). First, use the default profile and set the Minecraft version the version you want. After that, save, run Minecraft once and quit the launcher. Get the latest version of forge for your Minecraft version and run the installer. The reason why it needs you to run Minecraft 1.7.2 is because it is adding classes to the 1.7.2.jar file and installing patches. After that, reopen the Minecraft launcher and select the "Forge" profile. Minecraft Forge should then launch without problems

Answer (score -1):

1.7.4 is not released yet, but you can play forge in 1.7.2